# How to choose three vertices having maximum number of interconnecting edges?

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks

I have a set of edges as follows:

```
edges = {{1, 5}, {1, 72}, {5, 72}, {1, 7}, {1, 59}, {7, 59}, {1, 8}, {1, 
  45}, {8, 45}, {1, 10}, {1, 73}, {10, 73}, {1, 12}, {1, 18}, {12, 
  18}, {1, 13}, {1, 15}, {13, 15}, {1, 15}, {1, 29}, {15, 29}, {1, 
  19}, {1, 22}, {19, 22}, {1, 28}, {1, 35}, {28, 35}, {1, 37}, {1, 
  38}, {37, 38}, {1, 43}, {1, 52}, {43, 52}, {1, 48}, {1, 67}, {48, 
  67}, {1, 59}, {1, 71}, {59, 71}, {2, 3}, {2, 51}, {3, 51}, {2, 
  7}, {2, 36}, {7, 36}, {2, 11}, {2, 67}, {11, 67}, {2, 13}, {2, 
  56}, {13, 56}, {2, 17}, {2, 64}, {17, 64}, {2, 18}, {2, 35}, {18, 
  35}, {2, 20}, {2, 25}, {20, 25}, {2, 20}, {2, 37}, {20, 37}, {2, 
  20}, {2, 74}, {20, 74}, {2, 24}, {2, 35}, {24, 35}, {2, 26}, {2, 
  49}, {26, 49}, {2, 30}, {2, 42}, {30, 42}, {2, 32}, {2, 67}, {32, 
  67}, {2, 37}, {2, 49}, {37, 49}, {2, 40}, {2, 47}, {40, 47}, {3, 
  4}, {3, 74}, {4, 74}, {3, 13}, {3, 51}, {13, 51}, {3, 14}, {3, 
  70}, {14, 70}, {3, 16}, {3, 45}, {16, 45}, {3, 18}, {3, 45}, {18, 
  45}, {3, 30}, {3, 63}, {30, 63}, {3, 31}, {3, 65}, {31, 65}, {3, 
  44}, {3, 45}, {44, 45}, {4, 5}, {4, 29}, {5, 29}, {4, 6}, {4, 
  9}, {6, 9}, {4, 6}, {4, 67}, {6, 67}, {4, 10}, {4, 74}, {10, 
  74}, {4, 12}, {4, 60}, {12, 60}, {4, 13}, {4, 69}, {13, 69}, {4, 
  16}, {4, 24}, {16, 24}, {4, 18}, {4, 55}, {18, 55}, {4, 19}, {4, 
  65}, {19, 65}, {4, 28}, {4, 39}, {28, 39}, {4, 32}, {4, 55}, {32, 
  55}, {4, 32}, {4, 64}, {32, 64}, {4, 33}, {4, 62}, {33, 62}, {4, 
  43}, {4, 50}, {43, 50}, {4, 51}, {4, 70}, {51, 70}, {4, 56}, {4, 
  71}, {56, 71}, {5, 9}, {5, 12}, {9, 12}, {5, 9}, {5, 61}, {9, 
  61}, {5, 10}, {5, 48}, {10, 48}, {5, 20}, {5, 61}, {20, 61}, {5, 
  21}, {5, 67}, {21, 67}, {5, 24}, {5, 75}, {24, 75}, {5, 32}, {5, 
  45}, {32, 45}, {5, 41}, {5, 45}, {41, 45}, {5, 41}, {5, 53}, {41, 
  53}, {5, 44}, {5, 51}, {44, 51}, {5, 48}, {5, 53}, {48, 53}, {5, 
  49}, {5, 64}, {49, 64}, {5, 53}, {5, 61}, {53, 61}, {6, 7}, {6, 
  69}, {7, 69}, {6, 10}, {6, 62}, {10, 62}, {6, 12}, {6, 56}, {12, 
  56}, {6, 12}, {6, 58}, {12, 58}, {6, 12}, {6, 75}, {12, 75}, {6, 
  17}, {6, 69}, {17, 69}, {6, 18}, {6, 32}, {18, 32}, {6, 18}, {6, 
  44}, {18, 44}, {6, 20}, {6, 51}, {20, 51}, {6, 29}, {6, 52}, {29, 
  52}};
```

Now I wish to chose `3` vertices `v1` `v2` and `v3` such that there exists at least one edge between any two of these vertices and the number of edges among these `3` vertices is maximum. I can get the frequencies as follows:

```
frequencies = ReverseSortBy[Tally@edges, Last];
```

which gives me

```
{{{6, 12}, 3}, {{5, 61}, 3}, {{5, 53}, 3}, {{3, 45}, 3}, {{2, 20}, 
  3}, {{6, 69}, 2}, {{6, 18}, 2}, {{5, 48}, 2}, {{5, 45}, 
  2}, {{5, 41}, 2}, {{5, 9}, 2}, {{4, 74}, 2}, {{4, 55}, 2}, {{4, 32},
   2}, {{4, 6}, 2}, {{3, 51}, 2}, {{2, 67}, 2}, {{2, 49}, 
  2}, {{2, 37}, 2}, {{2, 35}, 2}, {{1, 59}, 2}, {{1, 15}, 
  2}, {{59, 71}, 1}, {{56, 71}, 1}, {{53, 61}, 1}, {{51, 70}, 
  1}, {{49, 64}, 1}, {{48, 67}, 1}, {{48, 53}, 1}, {{44, 51}, 
  1}, {{44, 45}, 1}, {{43, 52}, 1}, {{43, 50}, 1}, {{41, 53}, 
  1}, {{41, 45}, 1}, {{40, 47}, 1}, {{37, 49}, 1}, {{37, 38}, 
  1}, {{33, 62}, 1}, {{32, 67}, 1}, {{32, 64}, 1}, {{32, 55}, 
  1}, {{32, 45}, 1}, {{31, 65}, 1}, {{30, 63}, 1}, {{30, 42}, 
  1}, {{29, 52}, 1}, {{28, 39}, 1}, {{28, 35}, 1}, {{26, 49}, 
  1}, {{24, 75}, 1}, {{24, 35}, 1}, {{21, 67}, 1}, {{20, 74}, 
  1}, {{20, 61}, 1}, {{20, 51}, 1}, {{20, 37}, 1}, {{20, 25}, 
  1}, {{19, 65}, 1}, {{19, 22}, 1}, {{18, 55}, 1}, {{18, 45}, 
  1}, {{18, 44}, 1}, {{18, 35}, 1}, {{18, 32}, 1}, {{17, 69}, 
  1}, {{17, 64}, 1}, {{16, 45}, 1}, {{16, 24}, 1}, {{15, 29}, 
  1}, {{14, 70}, 1}, {{13, 69}, 1}, {{13, 56}, 1}, {{13, 51}, 
  1}, {{13, 15}, 1}, {{12, 75}, 1}, {{12, 60}, 1}, {{12, 58}, 
  1}, {{12, 56}, 1}, {{12, 18}, 1}, {{11, 67}, 1}, {{10, 74}, 
  1}, {{10, 73}, 1}, {{10, 62}, 1}, {{10, 48}, 1}, {{9, 61}, 
  1}, {{9, 12}, 1}, {{8, 45}, 1}, {{7, 69}, 1}, {{7, 59}, 
  1}, {{7, 36}, 1}, {{6, 75}, 1}, {{6, 67}, 1}, {{6, 62}, 
  1}, {{6, 58}, 1}, {{6, 56}, 1}, {{6, 52}, 1}, {{6, 51}, 
  1}, {{6, 44}, 1}, {{6, 32}, 1}, {{6, 29}, 1}, {{6, 20}, 
  1}, {{6, 17}, 1}, {{6, 10}, 1}, {{6, 9}, 1}, {{6, 7}, 1}, {{5, 75}, 
  1}, {{5, 72}, 1}, {{5, 67}, 1}, {{5, 64}, 1}, {{5, 51}, 
  1}, {{5, 49}, 1}, {{5, 44}, 1}, {{5, 32}, 1}, {{5, 29}, 
  1}, {{5, 24}, 1}, {{5, 21}, 1}, {{5, 20}, 1}, {{5, 12}, 
  1}, {{5, 10}, 1}, {{4, 71}, 1}, {{4, 70}, 1}, {{4, 69}, 
  1}, {{4, 67}, 1}, {{4, 65}, 1}, {{4, 64}, 1}, {{4, 62}, 
  1}, {{4, 60}, 1}, {{4, 56}, 1}, {{4, 51}, 1}, {{4, 50}, 
  1}, {{4, 43}, 1}, {{4, 39}, 1}, {{4, 33}, 1}, {{4, 29}, 
  1}, {{4, 28}, 1}, {{4, 24}, 1}, {{4, 19}, 1}, {{4, 18}, 
  1}, {{4, 16}, 1}, {{4, 13}, 1}, {{4, 12}, 1}, {{4, 10}, 1}, {{4, 9},
   1}, {{4, 5}, 1}, {{3, 74}, 1}, {{3, 70}, 1}, {{3, 65}, 
  1}, {{3, 63}, 1}, {{3, 44}, 1}, {{3, 31}, 1}, {{3, 30}, 
  1}, {{3, 18}, 1}, {{3, 16}, 1}, {{3, 14}, 1}, {{3, 13}, 1}, {{3, 4},
   1}, {{2, 74}, 1}, {{2, 64}, 1}, {{2, 56}, 1}, {{2, 51}, 
  1}, {{2, 47}, 1}, {{2, 42}, 1}, {{2, 40}, 1}, {{2, 36}, 
  1}, {{2, 32}, 1}, {{2, 30}, 1}, {{2, 26}, 1}, {{2, 25}, 
  1}, {{2, 24}, 1}, {{2, 18}, 1}, {{2, 17}, 1}, {{2, 13}, 
  1}, {{2, 11}, 1}, {{2, 7}, 1}, {{2, 3}, 1}, {{1, 73}, 1}, {{1, 72}, 
  1}, {{1, 71}, 1}, {{1, 67}, 1}, {{1, 52}, 1}, {{1, 48}, 
  1}, {{1, 45}, 1}, {{1, 43}, 1}, {{1, 38}, 1}, {{1, 37}, 
  1}, {{1, 35}, 1}, {{1, 29}, 1}, {{1, 28}, 1}, {{1, 22}, 
  1}, {{1, 19}, 1}, {{1, 18}, 1}, {{1, 13}, 1}, {{1, 12}, 
  1}, {{1, 10}, 1}, {{1, 8}, 1}, {{1, 7}, 1}, {{1, 5}, 1}}
```

By observation `{6, 12}` has `3` edges and the next sorted occurrence of `6 or 12` is `{6, 69}` which has `2` edges, however, `{12, 69}` has no edge. For `{5, 61}`, the next occurrence is `{5, 53}` and both have  `3` edges each and also there is an edge connecting `{53, 61}`. How can I choose these three variables `{5, 53, 61}`?

Comment: Are you simply looking for triangles?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Not really. Triangulation is one criterion as indicated in the question. On top of that, I need to find out that triangle whose vertices have the maximum number of interconnecting edges.

Comment: So, finding all triangles would already be a first step, right? Szabolcs' package ``"IGraphM`"`` provides the function that can do that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use FindCycle and Subgraph:

```
g = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges];
```

Convert it to a simple graph since multiplicity doesn't necessary for this.

```
triangles = FindCycle[SimpleGraph[g], {3}, All];

subgraphs = Subgraph[g, #, AnnotationRules -> None] & /@ triangles;
VertexList[First[MaximalBy[subgraph, EdgeCount]]]
```

> {5, 53, 61}

or

```
MaximalBy[triangles, 
 EdgeCount[Subgraph[g, #, AnnotationRules -> None]] &]
```

> `{{5 \[UndirectedEdge] 53, 53 \[UndirectedEdge] 61, 61 \[UndirectedEdge] 5}}`

Answer (score 4):

I would do it like this with [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM):

Create a graph:

```
g = Graph[UndirectedEdge @@@ edges];
```

Merge parallel edges and record the multiplicities as edge weights:

```
wg = IGWeightedSimpleGraph[g];
```

Now we find the maximum total edge weight triangle:

```
MaximalBy[
  IGTriangles[g], 
  Total@IGEdgeProp[EdgeWeight]@IGWeightedSubgraph[wg, #] &
]

(* {{5, 61, 53}} *)
```

This will work in Mathematica 10.0 and later.

In Mathematica 12.0 or later, you can use `Subgraph` instead of `IGWeightedSubgraph`, as it does preserve weights.

A bit more complicated than @halmir's version, but I wanted to show how to work with edge weights. The main advantage of this answer is that `IGTriangles` is faster than `FindCycle` (because it is more specialized).

---

Note: You may be thinking of this problem as finding maximum-weight 3-cliques. IGraph/M does have a function called `IGWeightedCliques`, but it works with vertex-weights, not edge-weights. I am noting this just to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

You can employ Szabolcs' package `` "IGraphM`" `` to find all triangles first (if there are any). Then finding the a triangle with maximal number of edges attached to it is straight-forward:

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]
G = Graph[Range[Max[edges]], UndirectedEdge @@@ edges];
triangles = IGTriangles[G];
i = Ordering[Total[Partition[VertexDegree[G][[Flatten[triangles]]], 3], {2}], -1][[1]];
triangles[[i]]
```

Comment: Hm. Please restart the kernel. Could be that this clash stems from the installation process of ``"IGraphM`"``...

Comment: Hm ... I think this is incorrect. The vertex degre you compute is in the entire graph, but we want to maximize the number of edges in the 3-vertex subgraph (triangle).

Comment: Can you clarify what clash you are referring to? I you just upgraded the package, please do restart the kernel. I am having trouble unloading the LibraryLink component recently, not sure why ... thus a kernel restart is necessary after installing a new version on most platforms.

Comment: @Szabolcs Majis told me that _Mathematica_ gave the shadowing warning for  `IGTriangle`. Seemingly, a kernel restart indeed solved it.

Comment: Ah, it was just shadowing.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.

With Version 10

```
sedges = Sort[edges]
sant   = Min[edges];
cont   = Table[0, Max[sedges]]

For[i = 1, i <= Length[sedges], i++, se = sedges[[i]]; 
  If[se[[1]] == sant, cont[[sant]]++, cont[[se[[1]]]]++]; 
  sant = se[[1]]
]
```

Now **cont** has the incidences per knot in increasing order. After that

```
FindShortestPath[edges, 2, 4]
FindShortestPath[edges, 4, 1]
FindShortestPath[edges, 1, 2]
```

Comment: I do not understand how this obtains the result `{{5, 61, 53}}`.

Comment: After the **Sort** we have the edges sorted by the first knot. After the **For** we have how many edges are connected to any knot. It gives for **cont** the values $\{26,30,17,33,28,22,\cdots.,\}$ Those number of "visits" are regarding the knots $\{1,2,3,4,5,\cdots,\}$ now with **FindShortestPath** we can find if the most visited knots are connected by a path etc.